# how i will write Laravel ifelse condition in views

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel-7

Hi i am stuck in writing the URL inside of ifelse statement in laravel. please find the code below

```
<body @if(Request::path('/contact')) class="single-page contact-page" 
@elseif(Request::path('/about')) class="single-page about-page"
    @elseif(Request::path('/causes')) class="single-page causes-page"
    @endif>
```

Comment: Create a view composer (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers) and pass the css class from there

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for this. I write 2 below. You can use whatever you want.

```
<body @if(request()->path() == "/contact") class="single-page contact-page"
      @elseif(request()->path() =='/about') class="single-page about-page"
      @elseif(request()->path() == '/causes') class="single-page causes-page"
    @endif>
```

or

```
@php
    $className = "";
    if(request()->path() == "/contact") {
        $className = "contact-page";
    } elseif(request()->path() == "/about") {
        $className = "about-page";
    } elseif(request()->path() == "/causes") {
        $className = "causes-page";
    }
@endphp
<body class="single-page {{ $className }}">
```